# Finding a div with certain link inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I'm given a class of a `div $('.my_class')` and that a `div` contains a link `a` with a certain url which I'm also given, how do I find this `div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
$('div.my_class a[href="LINK"]').closest('div.my_class');
```

Comment: Won't work if there are other elements with the class `my_class`, and if the link isn't a direct child of the div.

Answer (score 2):

First find the link that is a child of your .my_class, then find the closest parent with that class. That will return you the original div:

`$('.my_class a[href="mylink.com"]').closest('.my_class');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var certain_url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
//...
var the_link = $('div.my_class a[href="'+certain_url+'"]').closest('div.my_class')
```

Comment: Not quite right.  The link must be inside a div with class `my_class` and `closest` will return any element with the specified class, not just divs.

Comment: No worries and +1 for being the only one on here that covers all eventualities suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your markup looks like this:

```
<div class="my_class">
   <a href="some_link">Click me</a>
</div>
```

So in jQuery it would look like:

```
$(".my_class").find("a[href='some_link']").closest(".my_class");
```

Comment: You didn't specify that you needed the first link, or the first div for that matter

Comment: This will find the link, not the `div`

Comment: @colestrode updated because i didn't see the last `div` in the question.

Comment: @AlanDert See the edit - that will select the first div (parent) of the anchor.

Comment: `closest()` needs at least one parameter

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
$('div.my_class a[href="mylink"]').parent();
```

Comment: This selects the link, not the div

Comment: Is the div the parent, or have you assumed it's the parent?